# Error showing special prices when changing store view - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, store-view, customer-group, special-price

I have 2 store views, one for normal customers (product prices including tax) and one for wholesale customers (product prices excluding tax). See images for reference.

**Normal Store View (product prices including tax):**
[image]

**Wholesale Store View (product prices excluding tax):**
[image]

And additionally, I have special prices for the customer group Wholesale in some products like this:

[image]

When I log in with a wholesale account for example in the store view EN (prices including tax), I see the correct special prices.

[image]

But when in the same session I change the store view, I lose the special prices and I only see the normal customer prices:

[image]

If I log in with a wholesale account but now in the store view Wholesale (prices excluding tax), I see the correct special prices too:

[image]

But when in the same session I change the store view, I lose the special prices and I only see the normal customer prices again:

[image]

I don't understand why, this happens to me only if I change the store view and it is very strange right? Is this an error for Magento? Any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

**UPDATE 1**

The entity_id of this product is 2726, the customer_group_id is "2" (Wholesale group) and this is the result of Query:

> SELECT * FROM catalog_product_index_price WHERE entity_id = 2726;

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

This is the configuration that I have for my taxes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can someone help me fix this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had your same problem and I have solved it in the following way:

**Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration**

Check that you have this option in NO. I used to have it in YES so that Magento automatically assigned the Wholesale group to my customers and I had the same problem as you. Disabling this option you can fix your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hey Please check in catalog_product_index_price table with your entity_id. Like SELECT * 
FROM  `catalog_product_index_price` WHERE entity_id =432 LIMIT 0 , 30 and see what price is there.

Comment: the entity_id for this product is "2726" and you can see the result of this query in my question (Update 1), the normal price is 13,18€ and the special price (25% discount for wholesale group) is 9,89€. What can I do now? Do you know how to solve the problem that I have?

Comment: Please delete all Special price and tax rules and then one by one add it and debug it in the front end if you are not a developer.

Comment: I am a developer and I have access to the database. The problem is that I have restored an old version of my Magento, before installing plugins and put special prices. I have put a special price only in this product, and the error is the same. I do not know how to solve this, could you help me please?

Comment: Can we talk by chat about my problem please? I think that will be more faster by chat

Comment: Flush the cash and reindex If the problem will not solve then check the rules which you are giving and yes also check tax rules also This is not a coding issue.

Comment: Is the problem a configuration or is it an internal Magento problem?

Comment: This is not Magento problem I think this is a configuration issue. Please check it twice, check in private window and yes reindex it by command "php bin/magento indexer:reindex"

Comment: I have cleaned cache and reindexed several times and continue with the same problem. I have updated my question (Update 2) with the configuration of my taxes in the store. It is right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94765/discussion-between-despotars-and-krunal-pandya).